# Nested SCSS and targeting the parent

Tags: html, css, sass

I nest SCSS quite a lot and I'm able to target the parent element using `&` but in this instance it's giving me a headache! I feel like I'm missing something quite obvious but I can't get it to work. Here's my (simplified) SCSS:

```
[class^="icon--"]:before,
[class*=" icon--"]:before {
    opacity: .50;
}
```

Basically I'm using an icon font and I want the icons (added using the :before element) to appear lighter than the text it's attached to - fine.

Now I want to overwrite this on certain elements this class is applied to. I've tried to following (below), which does remove the opacity from the targeted element ...but it also seems to cancel out the `opacity: .50;` on every element. So basically everything has `opacity: 1;` set.

```
[class^="icon--"]:before,
[class*=" icon--"]:before {
    opacity: .50;

    @at-root {

        .btn#{&} {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your problem still not solved?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the following SCSS:

```
[class^="icon--"],
[class*=" icon--"] {
  &:before {
    opacity: .50;
  }    
  &.btn  {
    &:before {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

which renders to this CSS:

```
[class^="icon--"]:before,
[class*=" icon--"]:before {
  opacity: .50;
}
[class^="icon--"].btn:before,
[class*=" icon--"].btn:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

`&` references the selector that will be built so far in your level of nesting (not necessarily only the parent, only if nesting level is one).

Your attempt would create this CSS:

```
[class^="icon--"]:before,
[class*=" icon--"]:before {
  opacity: .50;
}
[class^="icon--"]:before.btn,
[class*=" icon--"]:before.btn {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Which would expect a class `.btn` on a pseudo element `:before` (which you cannot have).

You can easily check on [sassmeister.com](http://www.sassmeister.com/). Here is a really helpful article on [the almighty ampersand in SCSS](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my example was just 1 thing I tried. I go into more detail in the comment below it. I don't think your version will work as it puts a space between `.btn` and the `[class^="icon--"]:before`. It would need to be `.btn[class^="icon--"]:before` - no spaces.

Comment: I was assuming you are using an element with the class .btn inside your button. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: No sorry, I should've been clearer sorry. For some reason I struggled to explain myself! I tried using stuff like `@at-root {}` and `.btn#{&}` ...but obviously that wasn't right either and I'm quite new to that stuff too. Thanks again for your replies!

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply. I think I made a problem for myself by started off with `[class^="icon--"]:before` rather than nesting the `&:before` like you have done in your example. I think that's probably the best way of handing it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with SCSS but it looks like you're trying to target

```
[class*=" icon--"]:before.btn
```

A class btn in a pseudo-element, this might be the problem

Comment: Hi, yeah I just put the example like that. I got into the other ways I've tried to target it in the comment below, using `&` for example. Just can't get it to work any way!